# 'KerasLayer' object has no attribute 'layers'

Tags: tensorflow, keras-layer, tf.keras, tensorflow-hub

I'm trying to customize the model taken from tf hub but
can't access the layers with following error  *'KerasLayer' object has no attribute 'layers'*

Here is my code as an example:

```
import tensorflow_hub as hub

from tensorflow.keras import layers

feature_extractor_url = "https://tfhub.dev/tensorflow/efficientnet/lite0/feature-vector/1" 

base_model = hub.KerasLayer(feature_extractor_url,
                                         input_shape=(224,224,3))

base_model.trainable = True


import tensorflow
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model

x =  base_model.layers[-10].output
x = tensorflow.keras.layers.Conv2D(4, (3, 3), padding="same", activation="relu")(x)
x = tensorflow.keras.layers.GlobalMaxPooling2D()(x)
x = tensorflow.keras.layers.Flatten()(x)
outputs = tensorflow.keras.layers.Activation('sigmoid', name="example_output")(x)

model = Model(base_model.input, outputs=outputs)

model.summary()

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-43-0501ec56d6c4> in <module>()
     14 from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
     15 
---> 16 x =  base_model.layers[-10].output
     17 x = tensorflow.keras.layers.Conv2D(4, (3, 3), padding="same", activation="relu")(x)
     18 x = tensorflow.keras.layers.GlobalMaxPooling2D()(x)

AttributeError: 'KerasLayer' object has no attribute 'layers'
```

What I've tried: 
I  built the model using sequential api :

```
model = tf.keras.Sequential([
  base_model,
  layers.Dense(image_data.num_classes)
])

model.summary()
```

But still a I can't access the layers inside base_model.

How can I access the layers from KerasLayer?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

You can access the layers via weights of the *Hub* model.

The topic is not straightforwardly mentioned in the TF-docs unfortunately. This is the depth I could dig up to so far and hopefully it sheds some light on accessing layers on *Hub*.

TF 2.5.0 & TF-Hub 0.12.0 have been used for the below tests.

1. Layers in **KerasLayer** object

```
>>> import tensorflow_hub as hub
>>> model = hub.KerasLayer("https://tfhub.dev/deepmind/ganeval-cifar10-convnet/1")
>>> model
<tensorflow_hub.keras_layer.KerasLayer object at 0x7f0c79372190>
>>> len(model.weights)
57
>>> model.weights[56]
<tf.Variable 'cifar10_convnet/linear/b:0' shape=(10,) dtype=float32, numpy=
array([-0.2734375 , -1.46875   ,  0.484375  ,  1.2265625 ,  0.53515625,
        0.96875   ,  0.3671875 ,  0.02282715, -0.7265625 , -1.078125  ],
      dtype=float32)>
>>> model.weights[56].name
'cifar10_convnet/linear/b:0'
```

Notice the above **weights** variable. KerasLayer has a *get_weights()* function as well. The difference in output is as below. Basically, the former is of type TF-Variable, and the latter is a numpy array.

```
>>> len(model.get_weights())
57
>>> model.get_weights()[56]
array([-0.2734375 , -1.46875   ,  0.484375  ,  1.2265625 ,  0.53515625,
        0.96875   ,  0.3671875 ,  0.02282715, -0.7265625 , -1.078125  ],
      dtype=float32)
```

To get, for example, the names of all layers, simply run:

```
layers = model.weights
[ layers[i].name for i in range( len(layers) ) ]
```

A hint of my output:

> 'cifar10_convnet/conv_net_2d/conv_2d_0/w:0',
>
> 'cifar10_convnet/conv_net_2d/conv_2d_0/b:0',
>
> 'cifar10_convnet/conv_net_2d/batch_norm_0/moving_mean:0',
>
> 'cifar10_convnet/conv_net_2d/batch_norm_0/moving_variance:0'

Note that weight, bias, mean, variance etc. are all listed separately as layers in the output.

---

2. Layers in **AutoTrackable** object

This is for low-level TF2 API users.

```
>>> import tensorflow_hub as hub
>>> model = hub.load("https://tfhub.dev/deepmind/ganeval-cifar10-convnet/1")
>>> model
<tensorflow.python.training.tracking.tracking.AutoTrackable object at 0x7f95943ec410>
>>> len(model.variables)
57
>>> model.variables[56]
<tf.Variable 'cifar10_convnet/linear/b:0' shape=(10,) dtype=float32, numpy=
array([-0.2734375 , -1.46875   ,  0.484375  ,  1.2265625 ,  0.53515625,
        0.96875   ,  0.3671875 ,  0.02282715, -0.7265625 , -1.078125  ],
      dtype=float32)>
```

Use "*variables*" instead of "*weights*" with this API.

Comment: Can I freeze this weights individually?

Answer (score 0):

The inner structure of the SavedModel loaded into a hub.KerasLayer is inaccessible. For this level of detail, you'll have to turn to EfficientNet source code instead.

Answer (score -1):

I met the same problem as you yesterday,but luckily for me, i have found two ways to solve the problem.

```
1.base_model = tf.keras.applications.MobileNetV2(input_shape=IMG_SHAPE,
                                               include_top=False,
                                               weights='imagenet'
                                               )
base_model.trainable = False
global_average_layer = tf.keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D()
prediction_layer = tf.keras.layers.Dense(59)
model = tf.keras.Sequential([
  base_model,
  global_average_layer,
  prediction_layer
])
model.summary()
....
fine_tune_at =100
for layer in base_model.layers[:fine_tune_at]:
  layer.trainable =  False
```

use the ' tf.keras.applications' with '.layers' together

2.Reference tensorflow documentation:https://tensorflow.google.cn/hub/tf2_saved_model?hl=en

```
base_model = hub.KerasLayer(feature_extractor_url,
                                     trainable=True,
                                     input_shape=(224,224,3))
```

model.summary()
Model: "sequential_2"

---

## Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #

keras_layer_1 (KerasLayer)   (None, 1024)              3228864

---

## dense_2 (Dense)              (None, 59)                60475

Total params: 3,289,339
Trainable params: 3,267,451
Non-trainable params: 21,888

I hope my answer will help you

Comment: This is unrelated to  his question. You are just putting the keras layer to the global model and perform the model summary for the global one. What he wants is accessing the layer in the model hub.